# Kali Linux can't find sbin/init

Tags: boot, kali-linux

I try to boot Kali Linux but I received this error:

```
switch_root: can't execute '/sbin/init': Exec format error
```

I tried Kali Linux recovery mode but nothing happened. I have Linux Mint and I saw the `/sbin/init` from Kali's volume and it says it's broken. How can I get this file repaired?

Comment: years go by, how you solve this problem?